# Remove "Published On" inside wp-admin

Tags: functions, wp-admin

How do I remove this? Preferaly would like to do an action hook inside functions.php to remove this. I don't want the editor to see/edit when they published the article.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hide it for non-admins with *CSS*:

```
function hide_curtime_wpse_96106() {
    if(get_post_type() === "post"){
        if(!current_user_can('manage_options')){
            // only for non-admins
            echo "<style>.misc-pub-section.curtime {display:none !important;} </style>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

---

**After:**

[image: After]

Comment: Just be forewarned that adding the hook to `admin_head-post-new.php` means writers cannot *schedule* posts, either.  This means any post must be published immediately and not at a future date.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @EAMann. John you can just comment out the second action if you wanted to allow scheduling.

Comment: That's fine and thank you for your concern. I guess the only other future concern would be... how can I "allow it" for certain custom post types.... example I want to extend this function and allow the publish to show only on "press-releases" custom post type.

Comment: Also, hiding it via CSS only works for those without FireBug and a penchant for looking at the source.